# Attempting to Develop a ListView w/ Custom Text and an Image Header

Tags: android, image, listview

I am a history teacher trying to create a "Presidential Fact" application for my class and I have minimal development experience. After watching tutorial after tutorial, I am at a loss.

Right now my code looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#1C1C1C"
    android:cacheColorHint="#1C1C1C"
    android:entries="@array/facts"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</ListView>
```

But this only provides the listview and I cannot change the font size. I am also clueless as to position the list in a way which allows for an image header.

[This is the general layout I am looking for](http://postimg.org/image/gaq0kfd3d/)

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you so much!

EDIT: I do know how to add elements to/populate my list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line of code to position the listView below an ImageView (or any other View).

```
android:layout_below="@+id/your_imageview"
```

So your updated listView would look like this

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/your_imageview"
    android:background="#1C1C1C"
    android:cacheColorHint="#1C1C1C"
    android:entries="@array/facts"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```